# VBA: How to insert Vlookup value in the first empty cell/row

Tags: vba, vlookup

I'm trying to insert a Vlookup value in the first empty cell/row. 
Here's my code

```
Dim lookfor As Range
Dim searchrange As Range
Dim book1 As Workbook
Dim book2 As Workbook
Dim book2name As String

book2name = "Micros_export.xlsm"

Dim book2namepath As String

book2namepath = "C:\Users\pkechichian\Documents\Revamp\Micros_export.xlsm"

Set book1 = ThisWorkbook
Set book2 = Workbooks.Open(book2namepath)
Set lookfor = book1.Sheets("Actual").Cells(2, 4)
Set searchrange = book2.Sheets("Accpac").Range("E:H")

lookfor.Offset(2, 0).End(xlDown).Value = Application.VLookup(lookfor, searchrange, 3, False)
```

Thanks for the help and sorry for the formatting !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** after OP clarifications

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim book2namepath As String
    Dim searchrange As Range

    book2namepath = "C:\Users\pkechichian\Documents\Revamp\Micros_export.xlsm"
    Set searchrange = Workbooks.Open(book2namepath).Sheets("Accpac").Range("E:H") '<-- set range directly at workbook opening
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Actual") '<--| refer to "destination" sheet
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1).value = Application.VLookup(.Cells(2, 4).value, searchrange, 3, False) '<--| write lookup value in first empty cell below in column "D"
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False '<--| close opened workbook without saving changes
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit but it still returns the same result. Instead of applying the rows.count to the entire column "D", would it be possible to apply it only on a range (in this case "D4:D34"). The sheet is composed of 4 tables, of which the 2 first are empty (where I need to enter the values) and the 2 last are filled with formulas, and I think this is the problem. I can also create a new sheet where I would use your formula and then transfer to this sheet, but I'm sure a better way exists :) I will make sure to improve my posting skills, sorry for that ! Thanks again !

Comment: What's "the same result"? Be detailed in describing both starting data and corresponding results.

Comment: Data is still inserted in "D143" instead of "D4"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick answer! It works fine except that the value is not inserted at the right place. I've added some images to give you a better idea.

[The value should be inserted in "D4"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUuh5.png)
[This is where the value is inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMnMn.png)

Comment: given your data structure the code can be simpler: see edited answer and please mark it as accepted if it fulfills your question. BTW to reply to any answer you should add comments right below it while for enhancing your question (e.g.: to add a screenshot or else) you should edit your question itself. In any case never post a new answer unless you're posting an _actual_ answer to your question!